# @autowired annotation issue, not injecting bean in class, using Spring3.0, hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

following is my class:

```
package com.abc.trade.util;

public class StockTraderLogger {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("StockTraderLogger");

    @Autowired
    ConfigService configService; 




    public static void debug(Object className, Object logMessage) {     
        try {
            System.out.println("in debug.. ");
            StockTraderLogger stl =new StockTraderLogger();
            stl.addMessage(""+convertToString(className)+"\t"+convertToString(logMessage));
            System.out.println("in debug..post ");
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception...");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addMessage(String message) throws DataAccessException {
        System.out.println("in  add message of util. ");
        System.out.println("String: " + configService); 

        configService.addMessage(message);          
    }
}
```

`@Autowire` annotation is not working. It is displaying value of `configService` as **null** when called `addMessage` method. however it is properly injected in some of my Controller classes but not here.

Can anyone explain what is problem? and how to resolve this issue?

Code for XML is:(beansdefinition.xml)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop


   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.trade.util"/> 
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.trade.service"/>

       <!-- Hibernate Configuration -->
       <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">    

                <property name="annotatedClasses">      
                    <list>
          <value>com.abc.trade.model.Order</value>  
          <value>com.abc.trade.model.Profile</value> 
          <value>com.abc.trade.model.Log</value>                
                    </list>    
                </property>  
           </bean>

            <tx:annotation-driven/> 

           <bean id="transactionManager" 
               class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
          </bean>

           <bean id="commonService" class="com.abc.trade.framework.service.CommonServiceImplementor">
                <property name="commonDao" ref="commonDao"/>
           </bean>

           <bean id="commonDao" class="com.abc.trade.framework.dao.HibernateDAO">
            <property name="sessionFactory"><ref local="sessionFactory"/></property>

           </bean>

            <bean id="configService" class="com.abc.trade.service.ConfigServiceImplementor" parent="commonService">
           </bean>

           <import resource="../context/springws-servlet.xml"/>
     </beans>
```

Another XML is:(Springmvc-servlet.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>


     <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.trade.controller" />   
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.trade.util"/>


     <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Exception Resolver -->
     <bean id="exceptionResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="com.abc.trade.framework.exception.DataAccessException">
                errorPage</prop>
                <prop key="java.sql.SQLException">errorPage</prop>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">errorPage</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>   

</beans>
```

Thank you in advance.

`ConfigService`:

```
package com.abc.trade.service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.abc.trade.framework.exception.DataAccessException;

public interface ConfigService {

        public void addMessage(String message) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

Config Service Implementor:

```
package com.abc.trade.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.abc.trade.framework.exception.DataAccessException;
import com.abc.trade.framework.service.CommonServiceImplementor;
import com.abc.trade.model.Log;
import com.abc.trade.model.Mode;
import com.abc.trade.util.StockTraderLogger;

@Service("configService")
public class ConfigServiceImplementor extends CommonServiceImplementor implements ConfigService{

    String errorMessage = "";

    @Override
    public void addMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("in add message of service...........");
        Log log = new Log();
        try{
            log.setMessage(message);
            System.out.println("Message is: "+message);
            int i=save(log);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            errorMessage = "Error in saving debug message";
            e.printStackTrace();
            //throw new DataAccessException(errorMessage);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the full package class name of the ConfigService class?  I think default injection is by type, not by name.

Comment: I autowired this bean in controller and it is working fine but  if I autowired  in some other classes then it is not getting autowired.

Comment: Did u happen to solve the problem sagar????

Comment: @indyaah : No, Currently I'm not working on Spring.

Answer (score 8):

StockTraderLogger is not declared as spring bean and doesn't exist in spring context and for that reason the injection won't work.

```
<bean id="StockTraderLogger" class="com.abc.trade.util.StockTraderLogger"/>
```

or

```
@Component
public class StockTraderLogger { /**/ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the problem is in debug method:

```
    StockTraderLogger stl =new StockTraderLogger();
```

This is not spring managed. You can inject Spring managed bean into non-managed one in two ways.
Here you can inject configService in StockTraderLogger as:

1) By AutowireCapableBeanFactory:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beansdefinition.xml");
    StockTraderLogger stl = new StockTraderLogger();
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(stl, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
```

2) By using Spring AOP @Configurable annotation which marks a class as eligible for Spring-driven configuration(like objects instantiated with the 'new' operator).

```
    @Configurable
    public class StockTraderLogger {
    ...
    }

and specifying this <context:spring-configured/> in beansdefinition.xml.
```

You can find more information about this spring aop way [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Answer (score 2):

Add this to `applicationContext.xml`:

`xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`

and

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc` to `xsi:schemalocation`

mvc-annotation driven is required for annotated controllers and other features:

`<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Comment: I also tried this in my application, not working thats a serious issue. Lets close it as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Also make sure that your ConfigService class has

```
@Service("configService")
```

Annotation, it will make this class candidate for autowiring.

and of cause you should use

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package" />
```

for the ConfigService package name.

Comment: component scan is there in my XML, you can see that in XML code I shared in question itself. do I need to change it?

Comment: you need to changeor add new one which refers to configService package

Comment: you can check beansdefinition.xml, in that I added component scan which refers to service package. But same output.

Comment: Could you please post ConfigService code and it's interface code?

Comment: Does anybody has a proper solution for it. i also tried but not working. Lets close it as possible..

Comment: @akash746 check my answer for this issue.